# 4x4 Matrix not working with Arduino

Tags: arduino

I bought one new 4x4 keypad matrix and it is not working. I connected it like I should and used the example code, but it is not working. I can measure drops with multimeter but Arduino Serial shows nothing.

```cpp
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte numRows= 4; //number of rows on the keypad
const byte numCols= 4; //number of columns on the keypad

//keymap defines the key pressed according to the row and columns just as
//appears on the keypad
char keymap[numRows][numCols]=
{
{'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
{'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
{'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
{'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};

//Code that shows the the keypad connections to the arduino terminals
byte rowPins[numRows] = {5,4,3,2}; //Rows 0 to 3
byte colPins[numCols]= {6,7,8,9}; //Columns 0 to 3

//initializes an instance of the Keypad class
Keypad myKeypad= Keypad(makeKeymap(keymap), rowPins, colPins, numRows,
numCols);

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.print("Started at 9600");
}

//If key is pressed, this key is stored in 'keypressed' variable
//If key is not equal to 'NO_KEY', then this key is printed out
//if count=17, then count is reset back to 0 (this means no key is
  pressed during the whole keypad scan process
void loop()
{
char keypressed = myKeypad.getKey();
if (keypressed != NO_KEY)
{
Serial.print(keypressed);
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: What happens when you try? You should try reading the pins manually and writing the status to the serial first, and see which pins are being activated (if any) when you press the buttons.. and see if it's behaving as expected.

Comment: I only see "Started at 9600" and then I press buttons and in serial shows up nothing...

Comment: you might have selected wrong board type in Tools--> Board . select appropriate board type if not selected ( in your case UNO)